Write buffer to ffmpeg stdin and send websocket message after that
I am working on a streaming application in which user can stream videos in real time to my server usig websocket and media recorder. I have written my backend code using fastapi python and I setup a websocket endpoint that would receive buffer data from the frontend every two second. But the problem I am facing is here :-
process.stdin.write(data)
await websocket.send_json

Here the code ffmpeg process write could take some time to take a buffer and write a mp4 for it, but the websocket send json won't wait for it and thus just send the message back to the client, which is causing videos being too short and currupted once the user stops the recording.
Here is the full code
@router.websocket("/stream")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, token: str = Query(...), videoId: str = Query(...), authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    dataNumber = 1

    recordingFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"recording_{videoId}.mp4")

    command = [
        'ffmpeg', 
        '-y',
        '-i', 
        '-', 
        '-codec:v', 
        'copy', 
        '-f', 'mp4',
        recordingFile,
        # "-"
        # f'output{queueNumber}.mp4',
    ]

    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    try:
        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
                if not data:
                    break
                process.stdin.write(data)
                process.stdin.flush()
                await websocket.send_json({"chunkNumber": dataNumber, "status": 200})
                dataNumber = dataNumber + 1
            except RuntimeError:
                break      
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print(f"Client disconnected: {websocket.client.host}")
    finally:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        process.stdin.close()
        process.wait()
        process.terminate()

What I want to do is on each buffer send from the client, I want to make sure that ffmpeg writes that to the filesystem compeletly and than only to send the websocket message back to the client. And also, as the request are coming from the client every 2 second no matter what, If the write is taking too long for the previous message, I want to make sure that that the ffmpeg first write that part to the file and send the message and than do the newer one

Does this answer your question?

Related answers might also be found here and here

@Chris if possible can you please provide a example to my code? I am using processes and its little hard to figure would asyncio threadpools

@alpecca At least add a print before each break  in order to know why it stopped (maybe no data leads to a short video?). Also If I remember correctly, FFmpeg will put the "finished" signal in stderr (might be changed now). Don't close the process through a Finally, instead only close the process when FFmpeg tells you it is finished encoding. Another possible option, for when to close, is to use process.returncode. Check if there is anything given as returncode before clearing with  .flush...

@alpecca Finally you also likely want to be encoding as fragmented MP4 if possible.  The chunks can still be joined as one big file (or can be saved and played individually as N-duration segments). Investigate it (no need for M3U8 playlist file if making as one big frag-MP4 file)
